# Can't catch DBI error

Tags: perl, sql-server-2008, iis, dbi

I'm writing a Perl script and I can't seem to catch DBI errors, regardless of what I try. I tried this:

```
use DBI;

$db = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;DATABASE=nodepoint;UID=sa;PWD=test;") or print "Something happened.";
```

and this:

```
use DBI;

eval
{
    $db = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;DATABASE=nodepoint;UID=sa;PWD=test;");
};
if ($@) { print "Something happened."; }
```

Both fail to catch the error and instead I get this on the screen:

```
DBI connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;DATABASE=nodepoint;UID=sa;PWD=test','',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (SQL-08001) [state was 08001 now 01000]
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (SQL-01000) at C:\dev\test.pl line 5.
```

This is a big problem because when used on IIS it throws a `500.2 Bad Gateway` when it sees the error. I need to catch it so I can display a proper message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default error handling is:

```
RaiseError => 0
PrintError => 1
PrintWarn  => 0
```

You want to pass `PrintError => 0` to `connect`.

---

If you prefer to check for errors:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $passwd, {
   RaiseError => 0,
   PrintError => 0,
});

if (!$dbh) {
   die($DBI::errstr);
}
```

If you prefer to have exceptions thrown:

```
my $dbh = eval {
   DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $passwd, {
      RaiseError => 1,
      PrintError => 0,
   })
};

if (!$dbh) {
   die($@);
}
```